# Kind of background-top (as border-top)

Tags: html, css, background

I was wondering if is this possible, or not.

I have this rectangle, bordered with 1px solid black.

[image]

**CSS**

```
.box {border: 1px solid #000000}
```

---

Soon as I am actually developing an hand-draw template, I assume to have this in dropdown menus:

[image]

Is this possible, using `background` property?

**EDIT:** I don't know the size of the dropdown, and it's not good idea create it with fixed size (the menu need to be editable)

Comment: answer is yes you can do that with `background` property. If you want to know how, you will have to show us the code of your menu.

Comment: check the border-image css property http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-image.asp

Comment: WOW @arieljuod. I design about 4 years and this is the first time I've seen this...

Comment: Setting that as your background image with `background-size: 100%;` is also a solution, if you need more cross-browser support than border-image provides (though this will stretch the image).

Comment: I knew about background-size property @cjspurg. But once it stetch the image, as you mentioned, doesn't help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but it will need to be a fixed size if you don't find a solution that makes it expandable. I would leave the top open ended, and make the image rather tall with long sides so it can accommodate your content by anchoring it to the bottom of your drop down div.  Anything leftover will be cut off at the the top of the div anyways because the background is exclusive to it.